# Android Notifications - Action button on normal view notification (without expanding to big view)

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to create a notification for my app which has the usual icon, title and subtext but also the action button on the right hand side of the notification without having to expand into big mode. The lines of text will always be short, so there is plenty of space for the button. It currently looks like this

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfb0D.png)

But when it gets compressed to normal view by another notification, it looks like this and loses the button

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo0RH.png)

I have made a custom view with RemoteViews, but the problem with that is that I don't want to have to set the positions and styles of the icon and text manually. It would be much more reliable over multiple devices to let the system keep taking care of them.

Is it possible to just add my own button to the right hand side of how the notification appears in the second image? Kind of like combining one element of a remote view with the standard layout generated by Android? From what I've read, I don't think it's possible to just use the action button in normal view?

The reason I want to be able to do this is to allow the user to tap the alarm to acknowledge they've seen it so that it doesn't go off, but they still have the notification of the upcoming event. Clicking anywhere other than the alarm button should just open the app like normal.

Code wise, it looks like this, with the remote views commented out.

```
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(activity.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.custom_notification);

        String eventDescription = preferences.getString(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.next_event_description), "Freemasons run the country");
        String eventTime = preferences.getString(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.next_event_time), "00:00");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    activity.getSystemService(activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0 , intent, 0);

    Notification.Action action = new Notification.Action.Builder(
            Icon.createWithResource(activity, R.mipmap.alarm_icon),
            nextEventAlarmMinutes.toString(),
            pIntent).build();

    Notification.Builder builder  = new Notification.Builder(activity)
            //.setContent(remoteViews)
            .setContentTitle(eventDescription)
            .setContentText(eventTime)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.alarm_icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(action)
            //.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setWhen(0)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

The custom view xml just has a relative layout and a button

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

Is it possible that the relative layout is overwriting the whole thing and I can just use the button as a view on its own without a parent view holding it?

Comment: Embed your image in question instead of using url

Comment: @Matt can you please post part of the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a notification with media controls to show action buttons even when the notification is collapsed. See the documentation [here.](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#media-style)

Answer (score -2):

```
//Share intent
Intent shareAction = new Intent(this, ActShare.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntentShare = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345, shareAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.share, "Share", pendingIntentShare );

//Editintent
Intent EditAction = new Intent(this, ActEdit.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntentEdit = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345, EditAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.edit, "Edit", pendingIntentEdit);

//Share intent
Intent deleteAction = new Intent(this, ActDelete.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntentDelete = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345, deleteAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.delete, "Delete", pendingIntentDelete);
```

Add this code to addAction in your default android notification..

Comment: Sorry I don't see how this answers the question at all? Will this not just add three different actions to the notification and still require it to be in big mode?